# Move to the right cell in a Openedge browse

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl, enter

I need to move the cell selection in a browse to the cell on the right, when hitting the ENTER key.

By default, ENTER moves the selection to the next record, in the same column. I need to change that behaviour in one particular browse.

Example:

[image]

Selected field is row 1, column "Sacar de Lima".
If I hit ENTER, selected field will be row 2, column "Sacar de Lima".

What I need to do is: If I hit ENTER, the selection goes to row 1, column "Sacar de Lince".

I have tried to set a ENTER trigger to the field, but for some reason I just can apply it to the whole browser and that's not useful.
The browse is a "freeform query" of a temp-table.

I'm using Openedge 11.6.4 in Windows,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
   // Trigger Phrase for RETURN
   ON "RETURN" OF ColumnField1 IN BROWSE brwName DO:
      // select Column2
      APPLY "ENTRY" TO ColumnField2 IN BROWSE brwName .
      // select not the next row, just a return
      RETURN NO-APPLY.
   END.
```

Comment: I had tried that but without the "RETURN NO-APPLY". Now it works, thank you.

Comment: if you dont wont, the normal progress trigger to select the next row with a return, then you should use "RETURN NO-APPLY"

Answer (score 0):

This "answer" is just for comment one more thing: I needed the RETURN on the last right column to take me to the first left one of the next record, so I added:

```
ON "RETURN" OF tDistribucion.De102 IN BROWSE brwDistribucion DO:
  APPLY "ENTRY" TO tDistribucion.De001 IN BROWSE brwDistribucion.
  APPLY "CURSOR-DOWN" TO tDistribucion.De001 IN BROWSE brwDistribucion.
  RETURN NO-APPLY.
END.
```